# Windows 10 and HTTP/2

Tags: iis, windows-10, http2

I have set the *DuoEnabled* registry key to 1, so theoretically I have enabled HTTP/2 Server Support on IIS 10.0. I tested it on Google Chrome, Internet Explorer and Edge **locally** (on my server-computer) and indeed, HTTP/2 shows itself.

However, whenever I try to run the **online** server test https://www.h2check.org/ it always shows me "No support for HTTP/2 was found.". Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: My suspicion is that h2check.org is outdated and not detecting sites which simply announce "h2" instead of any of the draft versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your application uses windows authentication or not. http/2 fails on windows authentication:

> Windows authentication (NTLM/Kerberos/Negotiate) is not supported with HTTP/2. In this case IIS will fall back to HTTP/1.1.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis) for more information.